How to Optimize Memory Usage in PHP When Processing Large CSV Files Without Hitting the Memory Limit?
I’m working on a PHP script that processes large CSV files (up to 1GB in size) by reading the file, performing some transformations on each row, and then saving the results to a database. My current approach involves reading the entire file into memory using file_get_contents() and then splitting it by line, but this often results in memory exhaustion errors.
I’ve considered using fgetcsv() within a loop to process the file line by line, but I’m concerned about the performance and want to ensure that the script runs efficiently even with very large files. Additionally, I need to handle potential issues like malformed lines or different CSV formats (e.g., varying delimiters).
What are some best practices or patterns for handling large CSV files in PHP while minimizing memory usage and maintaining good performance? Are there any built-in functions, libraries, or techniques that can help optimize this process?
What I Tried:
Reading the Entire File with file_get_contents():
I initially tried using file_get_contents() to load the entire CSV file into memory and then split it into rows using explode("\n", $data). This approach worked for smaller files but quickly led to memory exhaustion errors when dealing with larger files (over 100MB).
Using fgetcsv() in a Loop:
I switched to using fgetcsv() within a while loop to process the file line by line. This method significantly reduced memory usage and allowed me to handle larger files without crashing. However, I noticed a performance drop, especially when processing files with a large number of rows. Additionally, handling different CSV formats (like varying delimiters and escape characters) became cumbersome.
Adjusting PHP’s Memory Limit:
I tried increasing the PHP memory limit using ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');, which helped to an extent, but it felt more like a temporary fix rather than an efficient solution. I also realized that this approach wouldn’t be scalable for even larger files.
What I Expected:
Efficient Memory Usage:
I was hoping to find a method that would allow me to process very large CSV files without exhausting the server’s memory, while still maintaining reasonable processing speed.
Improved Performance:
I expected that processing the file line by line with fgetcsv() would be faster than it turned out to be, especially for files with a high number of rows.
Scalability:
I’m looking for a solution that can scale with file size, allowing the script to handle files in the GB range without requiring excessive memory or processing time.
I’m open to suggestions on how to improve the current approach or if there are alternative methods or libraries that can help me achieve better performance and memory efficiency.

Unless you can absolutely guarantee that your input data will never ever contain line breaks inside any of the column values, approach #1 makes little sense to begin with. fgetcsv is of course slower at reading, because it can take escape characters into account.

I did it reading CSV file using fgetcsv() in a loop, but also splitting the process in batches, avoiding issues with max_execution_time and memory_limit.

Asking for recommendations for libraries is generally frowned upon on this site because it can lead to opinions. That said, I have a handful of them that are my go-tos for very specific things, and CSV reading/writing is one of them.

If you show us your current code, maybe we can make sensible suggestions that are relevant to where you are currently

"However, I noticed a performance drop" File reads are going to be an irrelevant and miniscule part of the overall performance when compared to database inserts. In any case, it's not the sort of thing you're going to expect to do in real time, it's the sort of thing that should be handed off to a job queue and run in the background. "handling different CSV formats became cumbersome." How so? You just pass a parameter.

"I need to handle potential issues like malformed lines" Note that you're not currently paying the computational cost of detecting such malformed lines. With explode(), you're not handling escape or delimiter characters at all, so the parsing is very fast but the use of either of these constructs will break your import. The performance "degradation" you're experiencing with fgetcsv() is not because you're reading one line at a time, but because you're now performing these extra checks.

fgetcsv() in a loop is the superior mechanism, and will yield the most resilient and scalable process. If your code is OO, then I would also recommend implementing it as a Generator.
That said, your performance issues are not coming from processing one line a time. Your performance issue is a result of you now doing proper CSV parsing, which fgetcsv() does and explode() does not.
For example, on my dev box:
Read the whole file into memory
$file = file_get_contents('/tmp/foo.csv');

Time: 0.495s
Memory: 1007.6Mb

Read the whole file into memory, explode() to lines
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('/tmp/foo.csv'));

Time: 0.870s
Memory: 2292.3Mb

This doubles both the time and memory requirement, not very scalable. Let's read the file one line at a time:
Read one line at a time
$fp = fopen('/tmp/foo.csv', 'r');
while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
}
fclose($fp);

Time: 0.764s
Memory: 0.5Mb

Huge difference in memory consumption, and it's faster than splitting lines by explode. Still, this time difference is completely irrelevant and not worth your time to address.
However, let's now consider the additional overhead of CSV processing. You're currently doing this (ostensibly) via explode() on a comma. This leaves you vulnerable to breakages as a result of escaping and quoting, but it's pretty fast:
Read the whole file, explode() to lines, explode() to fields
foreach (explode("\n", file_get_contents('/tmp/foo.csv')) as $line) {
    $row = explode(",", $line);
}

Time: 2.128s
Memory: 2292.3Mb

Time: 2.37s
Let's now do the same thing line-by-line, it should be faster:
Read one line at a time, explode() to fields
$fp = fopen('/tmp/foo.csv', 'r');
while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
    $row = explode(",", $line);
}
fclose($fp);

Time: 2.036s
Memory: 0.5Mb

This is fantastic, and a huge improvement over what you currently have. However, it's not resilient to malformed input. For example, this code will break if your CSV file contains:
foo,bar,"this is a\nmulti-line\ncomment, which also contains a comma"

So let's add some proper CSV parsing:
Read one line at a time, innate with fgetcsv()
$fp = fopen('/tmp/foo.csv', 'r');
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
}
fclose($fp);

Time: 44.390s
Memory: 0.5Mb

And there's your performance hit. It'll be the same if we read the file first and then use str_getcsv():
Read one line at a time, explicit with strgetcsv()
$fp = fopen('/tmp/foo.csv', 'r');
while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
    $row = str_getcsv($line);
}
fclose($fp);

Time: 44.695s
Memory: 0.5Mb

So, your slow timing is coming from the CSV parsing, and not the line-by-line read. If you are absolutely certain that your files will never contain escaped or quoted characters, then you can switch to a line-by-line read and continue to use explode() to get fields. You'll improve speed slightly and dramatically improve memory usage. At the very least however, you should count the number of elements in each row to ensure it matches what you're expecting.

Best Approach to Handling Large CSV Files
1 . Split the CSV File

Divide the 1GB CSV file into smaller, manageable files and Chunk Size: Split into files containing ~100,000 records each.

2 . Batch Insert

Optimize database performance by inserting records in batches,5,000 and 10,000 record batches each batch size as per your system

3 . Background Process

Ensure continuous processing without blocking the main application, background jobs or a task queue asynchronously.

